# Middleman loop through files in data folder

Tags: ruby, middleman, middleman-4

I am trying to figure out the right syntax for calling a range of files within the `/data` folder.

For example, I have a handful of files in `/data`, each formatted as `article1.yml`, `article2.yml`, etc. How might I loop through them in my template? I assume the most direct way would be calling an increment of numbers in the filename like this:

`<% data.article-[1,2,3].each do |article| %>
  <p><<%= article.title %></p>
<% end %>`

I've seen others ask [similar](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/iterate-multiple-files-inside-the-data-folder/1527) questions but haven't found a good example to look at that either loops through all available files, or like in my example loops through an increment of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anthonytkim are they in an a folder within data? i.e. /data/article/article1.yml? If so, to simply grab them all, try this:

```
<% data.article.each do |id, article| %>
... do stuff ...
<% end %>
```

To only grab a few items, try using the first() syntax:

```
<% data.article.first(7).each do |id, article| %>
... do stuff ...
<% end %>
```

If you want to grab a range from the middle, you can combine first(), and drop(). For instance, if I wanted items 5, 6, and 7:

```
<% data.article.first(7).drop(4).each do |id, article| %>
... do stuff ...
<% end %>
```

If you want to output them in the reverse order, try this (which you can also combine with the first() and drop() syntax):

```
<% data.article.reverse_each do |id, article| %>
... do stuff ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not only did this get me in the right direction, but it helped me solve a problem on another middleman project where I was trying to get the first (most recent) blog post. Thanks for the writeup!!

Answer (score 0):

Using Middleman 4.3.2, I was able to iterate through multiple files within a data folder like so:

```
<% data.article.each do |article| %>
  <p><%= data.article.fetch(article[0]).title %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the code above, `article` is set to some Array, like so: `['article_name', '#']`, so I was able to grab the first item in the array to fetch the specific article data.